# Error "unsupported character in float" when scraping metrics in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-java

I instrumented Prometheus Metrics and while I try to scrape them I got the "unsupported character in float" error.
Any idea why this error occurs?

Comment: When I got this error it was because the exposed metrics had a syntax error.